# No more SMTP inbound after upgrading Microsoft Azure Windows server VM

Tags: windows, azure, iis, smtp

After I upgraded my Azure VM, for Windows server 2012, from Standard D1 to Standard D2 there is no more incoming SMTP into \Inetpub\mailroot\pickup.   IE. If I send email to this server, no email arrives in pickup\ anymore.

How do I re-configure/re-start SMTP?

Server Mgr > Local Server > Services > SMTPSVC is running & Automatic
IIS6 MGR > local computer > SMTP Virtual Server #1 > Domains are all still there

I ran Wireshark and see incoming emails getting to this Windows Server VM, but not getting to:  \Inetpub\mailroot\pickup\

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem and solution...

Solution:  At VM Windows, control panel > Admin.. > IIS6 > right-click: SMTP Virtual Server > Properties > IP address > Pull-down and select VM's present private IP.
You can see the private IP at VM's Microsoft dashboard, or: Window server > power shell > type ipconfig, and that will show it.

PROBLEM:  Microsoft failed to report to me that it changed the private IP of my Microsoft Azure server when I did upgrade of VM from Standard D1 to Standard D2.

Comment: If you're not paying extra for a public/external IP on Azure, I believe they change it somewhat frequently (for example, after you shut down and restart the VM).

Answer (score 0):

Incoming SMTP arrives into Drop folder. Pickup is for outgoing email.